# char stored as int array in C? How to I convert it to C#

Tags: c#, c, arrays

I am trying to understand part of the C code and convert it to C# code. I have a hard time understanding this part, it seems like a char array, expressed with intergers. How do I convert it to C# code?

Thanks in advance!

```
static const char   gradient[32][4] =
{
    { 1,  1,  1,  0}, { 1,  1,  0,  1}, { 1,  0,  1,  1}, { 0,  1,  1,  1},
    { 1,  1, -1,  0}, { 1,  1,  0, -1}, { 1,  0,  1, -1}, { 0,  1,  1, -1},
    { 1, -1,  1,  0}, { 1, -1,  0,  1}, { 1,  0, -1,  1}, { 0,  1, -1,  1},
    { 1, -1, -1,  0}, { 1, -1,  0, -1}, { 1,  0, -1, -1}, { 0,  1, -1, -1},
    {-1,  1,  1,  0}, {-1,  1,  0,  1}, {-1,  0,  1,  1}, { 0, -1,  1,  1},
    {-1,  1, -1,  0}, {-1,  1,  0, -1}, {-1,  0,  1, -1}, { 0, -1,  1, -1},
    {-1, -1,  1,  0}, {-1, -1,  0,  1}, {-1,  0, -1,  1}, { 0, -1, -1,  1},
    {-1, -1, -1,  0}, {-1, -1,  0, -1}, {-1,  0, -1, -1}, { 0, -1, -1, -1},
};
```

Comment: This is a multi dimension array in C. Read about them here- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-c-cpp/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: `char` is an integer type, but plain `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned` and may not be able to hold a value of `-1`.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh I know it's a multidimensional array... I guess my problem is it's declared as a char array in C, but what's inside the array are intergers, C seems to handle it alright, but C# doesn't convert int to char directly...

Comment: @DavidBowling so does that mean char array cannot hold values like {-1,-1,-1,0}? What does {-1,-1,-1,0} as a char type?

Comment: Do you need it as char or as integers? If you need it as integers just declare it as a multi-dimensional int array.

Comment: @john I honestly don't kown. I don't know if chaning it to an int array in C# is the same as the char array in C

Comment: Again, `char` _is an integer type_; it is meant to hold integer values (not necessarily the full range of `int`). `char` may be `signed` or may be `unsigned`; this is implementation dependent. `char` can always hold a value of `0` or `1`, but may not be able to hold `-1`. The posted code is not portable. I don't know what this means for C#, though.

Comment: @DavidBowling sorry I am still confused...if char cannot hold -1, but the code I posted works just fine with -1s?

Comment: I did not say "cannot", I said "may not be able to." Whether `char` can hold negative values depends on the implementation, hence, not portable. It may work on your system, and fail on others. This was really just a comment about the posted code, but does not address your problem of converting to C#.

Comment: @DavidBowling okay, thank you! that make sense...

Comment: For C# I'd suggest just using an `int`, given the small size of the array.

Comment: [According to this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm) the C# `sbyte` type is an 8-bit signed integer type with a range of [-128,127]; this corresponds with `signed char` in C.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks, i think it'll work. I'll go head and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# equivalent of char is byte. But in your case you need possibility of negative numbers, so you’ll need a multidimensional array of sbyte.

Comment: C# `byte` would correspond to C `uint8_t`, which is an 8-bit `unsigned` integer type. Note that in C `char` is an integer type which may be `signed` or `unsigned`, and which must be _at least_ 8 bits wide, but may be wider.